# oracle last_value function and forecasting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, forecasting

I need to return a result set with the last value of the last date from my contracts, projects table; which later on I will need to use this result set to project the values for the remainig months of my forecast.
I dont seem to be getting anywhere, I need to take the last date,value pair per project & contract and project it.
I only have gone as far as the first part, which is to extract the last date,value; will also need help for the second part, which is to take this resulr and project it.
Here we go:

my table

```
contrato,projeto,data,valor
C001    P1  01-APR-15   10
C001    P1  01-APR-15   10
C001    P1  01-MAY-15   15
C001    P2  01-MAY-15   19
C001    P2  01-JUN-15   21
C002    P1  01-JUL-15   19
C002    P2  01-AUG-15   19
```

my query

```
select CONTRATO,PROJETO,FCST,
LAST_VALUE("PERIODO" IGNORE NULLS)OVER (PARTITION BY contrato,projeto,FCST,periodo   ORDER BY contrato,projeto,FCST RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)LAST_DATE
from(
select CONTRATO,PROJETO,periodo,
  LAST_VALUE("VALOR" IGNORE NULLS)OVER (PARTITION BY contrato,projeto,periodo,valor ORDER BY PERIODO,contrato,projeto RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )FCST
  FROM "HYP_STAGE"."INVENT_TABLE_FCST"
  )ORDER BY CONTRATO,PROJETO,PERIODO;
```

My result set , is repeating the values for the months, only need one value per month;

```
C001    P1  10  01-APR-15
C001    P1  10  01-APR-15
C001    P1  15  01-MAY-15
C001    P2  19  01-MAY-15
C001    P2  21  01-JUN-15
C002    P1  19  01-JUL-15
C002    P2  19  01-AUG-15
```

Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query, which you probably need:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c180a/1)

```
select distinct contrato, projeto, 
    last_value(periodo) over (partition by contrato, projeto 
      order by periodo nulls first 
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) p,
    last_value(valor) over (partition by contrato, projeto 
      order by periodo nulls first 
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) v
  from INVENT_TABLE_FCST order by contrato, projeto
```

For second part of your question about projecting results for future periods, you did not explain what you mean by forecasting result.

---

> If i have more variables like segments, products how wpuld the query be?

I suspect that segments and products should be treated the same way as contrato and projecto, so you need to add these columns to `select ...` part and in `partition  by...` parts.

But you may want to treat them analogically like `valor`, it depends on your needs.

> Second part , need to project the last month value for another 48 months ahead(fill with the same value)

For this we need some hierarchical query generating new periods, here I used [recursive CTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL):

```
with data(n, contrato, projeto, periodo, valor) as (
  select distinct 1, contrato, projeto,
      last_value(periodo) over (partition by contrato, projeto
        order by periodo nulls first 
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) periodo,
      last_value(valor) over (partition by contrato, projeto
        order by periodo nulls first 
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) valor
    from INVENT_TABLE_FCST  
  union all
  select n+1, contrato, projeto, add_months(periodo, 1), valor
    from data where n<48 )
select contrato, projeto, periodo, valor 
  from data order by contrato, projeto, periodo
```

> Perfect! It worked great!

So why not mark answer as accepted? ;-)

---

One more note: It would be very good if you had any primary key in your table, so we have distinct, incrementing 
value which makes partitioning and ordering correct for sure.

Comment: It worked Perfectly. If i have more variables like segments, products how wpuld the query be? Second part , need to project the last month value for another 48 months ahead(fill with the same value). Thanks a lot!